# Why Prometheus recording rule's result can differ from manual query?

Tags: prometheus, istio

I have the following recording rule:

```yaml
record: istio_slo:error_rate:ratio_rate2w
expr: |
  sum(rate(istio_requests_total{destination_app!="unknown", response_code=~"5.*"}[2w]))
  by (destination_service_namespace, destination_app, destination_service_name)
  /
  sum(rate(istio_requests_total{destination_app!="unknown"}[2w]))
  by (destination_service_namespace, destination_app, destination_service_name)
```

If I run manually the query inside the recording rule, I get a result different from the one returned by the recording rule itself:

[image: Result on Grafana]

Here is how I use the recording rule (in Grafana):

```
istio_slo:error_rate:ratio_rate2w{destination_service_namespace="$namespace", destination_app="$app", destination_service_name=~"$service"}
```

And the query:

```
sum(rate(istio_requests_total{destination_service_namespace="$namespace", destination_app="$app", destination_service_name=~"$service", response_code=~"5.*"}[2w]))   
/
sum(rate(istio_requests_total{destination_service_namespace="$namespace", destination_app="$app", destination_service_name=~"$service"}[2w]))
```

How would you explain such difference between results?

Comment: Hi, can You check if the results of only the first part before division matches on recording rule and manual query? If its possible also try to have it all in a single line in recording rule snippet.